# An Infinitesimal function can be decomposed into the product of two infinitesimal functions?

Tags: calculus

Let $f:U(x_0)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be an infinitesimal function, i.e. $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}f(x)=0$, then I will ask: does there exist two functions $g:U(x_0)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $h:U(x_0)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, such that $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}g(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}h(x)=0$, and $f=gh$ on some deleted neighbourhood of $x_0$?

I have known that if $f(x)=x^n$, $n\geq1$, then it satisfies the property. And the general case?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: If f(x)= x, what about $g(x)= h(x)= x^{1/2}$?  Or, if you don't want g and h the same, $g(x)= x^{1/3}$, $h(x)= x^{2/3}$?  Am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: What does "$U(x_0)$ mean? And what does "infinitesimal function" mean?

Comment: @user247327 Yes, you are right. I've known why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the terms you are using, but I imagine the following is an answer.

For any real-valued function $f$, we can define functions

$$ g(x) = \sqrt{|f(x)|} $$
$$ h(x) = \operatorname{sign}(f(x)) \sqrt{|f(x)|} $$

and then you will have $f(x) = g(x) h(x)$. Furthermore, if $f$ is continuous at $a$, then so are $g$ and $h$.

Comment: Thanks, I've just known why.